# How to return typed object based on function argument array?

Tags: typescript

I have a function which converts array values into keys in a object:

```js
function x(keys: string[]) {
  const obj: any = {};
  keys.forEach(v => {
    obj[v] = 'somevalue...';
  });
  return obj;
}

const result = x(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(result); // {a: "somevalue...", b: "somevalue...", c: "somevalue..."}
```

Is it possible to tell TypeScript that return value of this function will be `{<values of array>: string}` ?

Comment: Can you please give more context on why you want to convert array values into the keys of an object? I understand your questions, but not so much what you are trying to achieve. Were would the assignment of `somevalue...` really come from?

Comment: In this case I want to call a function that will read from a localStorage. I pass a list of keys to read and expect this function to return a object with key: value pairs.

Comment: How is the list of keys generated? Are the possible keys known in advance or may it be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is mostly called with constants, it makes sense to use a generic type parameter to capture the actual strings passed into the function in a generic type parameter. You can the use this type parameter with record to get a strongly typed object that will have the keys you specified.

```
function x<K extends string>(keys: readonly K[]) {
  const obj = {} as Record<K, string>;
  keys.forEach(v => {
    obj[v] = 'somevalue...';
  });
  return obj;
}

const result = x(['a', 'b', 'c']); //  Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>, same as {a: string, b: string, c: string}
result.a;
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
const result2 = x(keys);//  Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>

const skeys = ['a', 'b', 'c']// string[]
const result3 = x(keys);//  Record<string, string>, same as { [n: string]: string }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwGlEFNlS2AEwGdEioAnGMAcwD4AKAaywE8iAuRcrAQwIQA2LROgDaAXQCUiAN4AoRIggIyiOACMAVogC8sgL6IeJAEpZl5AhgA0pClToBuBYmZsAdMDjkAojwgAFvQAbrq0si6KGpqiweK6iADkRHAAtljBPAIgWO55ic6K+pKFXFhQIORI0c76cnLKYKrcRCACUAnI9KKJPIm2ier9SRCJUo6IAPSTimYWVgBEPAuIAD6IC+or6wsQC7ZklDS0BzzpRiQyPJyHDrbqN-Y0thCPR9R1LW1Q7jzOjao3CQ9D0+gMhgNRvFjEoVFAGnCyq12gAmTpMVhEErTWbmbyLZZrDZbIm7fZ2d60eoAjpEIEJUHDQZMqE4240CQIpodL7tADM6KB2JmiDm+NQ7OoByedFO5xhMkQojAbwc4lVNEQ+iAA)

If the function is called with an array that contains `string` you will get a plain index signature so you will not be worse off with this version.

Answer (score 2):

Since typescript's typings are only available at compile-time, there is no way for it to infer that information at runtime, esp. if the array is dynamically created. (If your keys are constant, have a look at [Titian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57623998/457268).)

For typescript, your array is an array of strings.

You can type your returned object of the `x` function with the [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) to avoid the any type hint:

```
const obj: {[key: string]: string} = {};
```

Yet keep in mind that it won't check for the existence of a key.

So the compiler will think that

```
const exists = obj["a"];
const doesntExists = obj["junk"];
```

are okay. You still have to check for undefined values.